# 1-d combined with 2-d array. Need functions calls for within main

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 1-d array and a 2-d array. I have them both in a function that I am using to read in information from a .txt file.

I have my arrays all set up and my functions set up correctly to my knowledge I just cannot figure out how to actually call the function that has 2 separate arrays in it. Here is the relevant information, please just let me know what I need to enter in main to call the functions. Thank you!

```
    void   getSales(double[][QUARTERS], int[]);     // places sales figures into the array
void   printSales(double[][QUARTERS], int[]);   // prints data as a table
void   printTableHeading();                     // prints table heading

int main()

{   
    double sales[YEAR_COUNT][QUARTERS]; // 2D array to hold the sales transactions
    int years[YEAR_COUNT];              // 1D array to hold the years
    return 0;
}

void printTableHeading()

{
}

void getSales(double salesTable[][QUARTERS],int yearArray[])
{
}

void   printSales(double salesTable[][QUARTERS], int yearArray[])
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main(
{
      getSales(sales, years);  // Will call your get sales function
      printSales(sales, years); // Will call your print sales function
}
```